# Parse Email Reply from Thread in Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I'm looking at parsing out just the most recent reply/message from an email thread as part of a zap.

I've found this link but how to I use it within a Zap? https://github.com/zapier/email-reply-parser

i.e. when I pick up a thread from gmail how do I just extract the most recent message?

Is this possible in Code by Zapier and if so how?

E.g.

**Input:**

Yes that is fine, I will email you in the morning.

On Fri, Nov 16, 2012 at 1:48 PM, Zapier  wrote:

> Our support team just commented on your open Ticket:
>   "Hi Royce, can we chat in the morning about your question?"

---

**Ouput:** i.e. the parsed email:

Yes that is fine, I will email you in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

First off: it's not possible to use that in a code step directly. Python code steps don't have access to external packages.

That said, that package is just Python code, and there's nothing stopping you copying all of the important code into the Code step and using it that way.

It's worth noting that the linked code is pretty old and looks to be unmaintained, so it's unlikely to work without modifications.

Comment: Thanks - I managed to copy the important code and hack it together.
Do you know of any better code to strip out email replies?

Comment: I don't, that's not something I've ever looked into! Also, if this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)) (or post your own)

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at adapting this https://github.com/zapier/email-reply-parser which seemed to work as well.

```
"""
    email_reply_parser is a python library port of GitHub's Email Reply Parser.

    For more information, visit https://github.com/zapier/email-reply-parser
"""

import re


class EmailReplyParser(object):
    """ Represents a email message that is parsed.
    """

    @staticmethod
    def read(text):
        """ Factory method that splits email into list of fragments

            text - A string email body

            Returns an EmailMessage instance
        """
        return EmailMessage(text).read()

    @staticmethod
    def parse_reply(text):
        """ Provides the reply portion of email.

            text - A string email body

            Returns reply body message
        """
        return EmailReplyParser.read(text).reply


class EmailMessage(object):
    """ An email message represents a parsed email body.
    """

    SIG_REGEX = re.compile(r'(--|__|-\w)|(^Sent from my (\w+\s*){1,3})')
    QUOTE_HDR_REGEX = re.compile('On.*wrote:$')
    QUOTED_REGEX = re.compile(r'(>+)')
    HEADER_REGEX = re.compile(r'^\*?(From|Sent|To|Subject):\*? .+')
    _MULTI_QUOTE_HDR_REGEX = r'(?!On.*On\s.+?wrote:)(On\s(.+?)wrote:)'
    MULTI_QUOTE_HDR_REGEX = re.compile(_MULTI_QUOTE_HDR_REGEX, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    MULTI_QUOTE_HDR_REGEX_MULTILINE = re.compile(_MULTI_QUOTE_HDR_REGEX, re.DOTALL)

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.fragments = []
        self.fragment = None
        self.text = text.replace('\r\n', '\n')
        self.found_visible = False

    def read(self):
        """ Creates new fragment for each line
            and labels as a signature, quote, or hidden.

            Returns EmailMessage instance
        """

        self.found_visible = False

        is_multi_quote_header = self.MULTI_QUOTE_HDR_REGEX_MULTILINE.search(self.text)
        if is_multi_quote_header:
            self.text = self.MULTI_QUOTE_HDR_REGEX.sub(is_multi_quote_header.groups()[0].replace('\n', ''), self.text)

        # Fix any outlook style replies, with the reply immediately above the signature boundary line
        #   See email_2_2.txt for an example
        self.text = re.sub('([^\n])(?=\n ?[_-]{7,})', '\\1\n', self.text, re.MULTILINE)

        self.lines = self.text.split('\n')
        self.lines.reverse()

        for line in self.lines:
            self._scan_line(line)

        self._finish_fragment()

        self.fragments.reverse()

        return self

    @property
    def reply(self):
        """ Captures reply message within email
        """
        reply = []
        for f in self.fragments:
            if not (f.hidden or f.quoted):
                reply.append(f.content)
        return '\n'.join(reply)

    def _scan_line(self, line):
        """ Reviews each line in email message and determines fragment type

            line - a row of text from an email message
        """
        is_quote_header = self.QUOTE_HDR_REGEX.match(line) is not None
        is_quoted = self.QUOTED_REGEX.match(line) is not None
        is_header = is_quote_header or self.HEADER_REGEX.match(line) is not None

        if self.fragment and len(line.strip()) == 0:
            if self.SIG_REGEX.match(self.fragment.lines[-1].strip()):
                self.fragment.signature = True
                self._finish_fragment()

        if self.fragment \
                and ((self.fragment.headers == is_header and self.fragment.quoted == is_quoted) or
                         (self.fragment.quoted and (is_quote_header or len(line.strip()) == 0))):

            self.fragment.lines.append(line)
        else:
            self._finish_fragment()
            self.fragment = Fragment(is_quoted, line, headers=is_header)

    def quote_header(self, line):
        """ Determines whether line is part of a quoted area

            line - a row of the email message

            Returns True or False
        """
        return self.QUOTE_HDR_REGEX.match(line[::-1]) is not None

    def _finish_fragment(self):
        """ Creates fragment
        """

        if self.fragment:
            self.fragment.finish()
            if self.fragment.headers:
                # Regardless of what's been seen to this point, if we encounter a headers fragment,
                # all the previous fragments should be marked hidden and found_visible set to False.
                self.found_visible = False
                for f in self.fragments:
                    f.hidden = True
            if not self.found_visible:
                if self.fragment.quoted \
                        or self.fragment.headers \
                        or self.fragment.signature \
                        or (len(self.fragment.content.strip()) == 0):

                    self.fragment.hidden = True
                else:
                    self.found_visible = True
            self.fragments.append(self.fragment)
        self.fragment = None


class Fragment(object):
    """ A Fragment is a part of
        an Email Message, labeling each part.
    """

    def __init__(self, quoted, first_line, headers=False):
        self.signature = False
        self.headers = headers
        self.hidden = False
        self.quoted = quoted
        self._content = None
        self.lines = [first_line]

    def finish(self):
        """ Creates block of content with lines
            belonging to fragment.
        """
        self.lines.reverse()
        self._content = '\n'.join(self.lines)
        self.lines = None

    @property
    def content(self):
        return self._content.strip()
return {'emailstring': EmailReplyParser.parse_reply(input_data['body'])}
```